# curl and grep commands output into a new variable

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am extracting information from a website. I designed the code in VBA and found that it is taking too long to execute. So, I have decided to rewrite the code in Unix script. I am extracting a page information using `curl` command as below.

```
page="$(curl http://www.somesitename.com/)"
```

Now, the variable `$page` contains the entire page contents in a HTML format. I am looking for a particular div class in the web page.

I use the grep command as below.

```
output=$("$page"|grep "div class=\"my_class_name\"")
```

If I just use `echo "$page"|grep "div class=\"my_class_name\""` I get the contents of div in the echo statement. However, as above when am trying to save it in a variable and printing, I am getting the entire HTML page contents as output.

I just need to check if the pattern `"div class=\"my_class_name\"` occurs in the page.

Comment: Will output="$($page|grep \"div class='my_class_name'\")" work. Encasing the entire command might do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and try using the following:

```
output="$($page|grep \"div class='my_class_name'\")"
```

Encasing the entire command in quotes should do the trick.